# What is the best way to implement multiple timers in kernel module

Tags: kernel, memory

I am trying to build e kernel module which will be used by userspace program to setup timers. I am implementing it as a character device. What is the best way to implement multiple timers in the kernel module?

Currently I have one 'timer_list*', sat 'timer'. I am assigning memory from the heap everytime I get a new request for timer and then use setup_timer() and mod_timer() to set the timer everytime I assign memory. But I am only using one pointer to the timer_list struct. But my concern here is that how to free the memory assigned to 'timer' once the callback function is called because the current value of 'timer' might not be pointing to the structure whose callback function is called.

So, I thought about passing the address of the structure in as an argument to the callback function and then call kfree() on that address.

```c
struct timer_list *timer;
timer = kmalloc(sizeof(struct timer_list), GFP_KERNEL);
setup_timer(timer, my_callback, (unsigend long)timer);
```

My callback function looks like this:

```c
void my_callback (unsigned long data)
{
      struct timer_list *timer = (struct timer_list*)data;
      printk("%d\n", timer->data);
      kfree(timer);
}
```

In this case I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to print timer->data saying there is no page for that particular address. So, is the the memoery allocated to timer_list freed when the callback function is called. In that case I dont need to worry about freeing the memory.

Also, is there a better way to implement this thing. Also, to keep a track of all the timers (like checking like existence of a timer), is it adivasable to maintain something like a linked-list or there is some kernel function to check this?

Answer (score 0):

```c
void my_callback (unsigned long data)
{
    struct timer_list *timer = (struct timer_list*)data;
    printk("%d\n", timer->data);
    kfree(timer);
}
```

I'm not a kernel hacker so I really can't suggest how to do it right, yet this generally looks rather like:

1. a rather suspicious type conversion from an integral type `unsigned long` to a pointer `struct timer_list *)`. I assume `data` is usually something small, so you are trying to access pages around `0`. Or it can be anything mostly random and hence most likely unmapped.
2. resource management gone wrong - I would also expect `timer` needing some sort of allocation before you can `free` it at the end. Even if the assignment and subsequent `printk()` went well (which I doubt), freeing random, previously not allocated memory should lead to crash.

Comment: If you look at the first part of the code, I am assigning memory to `timer` using kmalloc() and set the callback function. I am passing the address of the `timer` to the callback function. Since `data` in callback function is same as address of `timer`, I can use it like `struct timer_list*`

Comment: Oh, ok sorry, didn't read patiently enough - do you have some guarantee that `unsigend long` is at least the same size as `struct timer_list*` (or any pointer for that matter)? Apart from the fact that the compiler *seems* to do it right? By the way, why don't you `printk()` the values of `timer` to see where it is pointing to once you allocate it and before you try to dereference it?

Comment: The LDD book at chapter 7 page 199 says:


`If you need to pass multiple items in the argument, you can 
 bundle them as a single data structure and pass a pointer cast to
 unsigned long, a safe practice on all supported architectures and
 pretty common in memory management`

Comment: Well, my main problem with this is, that C specifies `long` as at least 4 bytes long. IIRC there is no guarantee that it will be the same size as a pointer (8 bytes on some architectures), although it often is the case.